# What is the term for the process of using 4 satellites or cell phone towers to locate a smartphone (or tracking device), including its altitude?

Tags: geometry, terminology, spheres

What is the process of using 4 satellites or cell phone towers to locate a smartphone (or tracking device), including its altitude, called?  I know for 2D this is trilateration but can't find a word for the 3D equivalent.
[image]

Comment: Trilateration means that the subject of the measurement is a distance (as opposed to triagulation, which measures angles). You can use them to define intersecting spheres.This is independent of the dimension in which you use it : in 2D you intersect the 3 spheres with the plane, but you still need 3 satellites or beacons to identify unambigously the location. In 3D you also need 3 satellites. The reason for using 4 or more satellites is to get better precision.

Comment: ^I thought 4 were needed to determine altitude (like the elevation at a spot on a mountain where someone is standing), while only 3 are needed for just latitude and longitude.

Comment: The distances are the radii of the spheres, so it is trilateration.

Comment: @John: The [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com) stack may be a better place for this question.

Comment: ^Thanks for the tip.  I'd like to keep it here too but is it possible to duplicate it and put it over there as well?  I'd prefer not to sign up for a new stack exchange just for one question.

Answer (score 1):

The process you are referring to is still called **trilateration**. In fact, the term "trilateration" can be used for both 2D and 3D positioning.

To clarify:

- **Trilateration** is the process of determining the location of a point (in 2D or 3D) by measuring distances to it from known points at the end of fixed baselines, rather than measuring angles to it as with triangulation.

For 2D positioning, you'd indeed need at least three non-collinear points (e.g., three cell towers) to uniquely determine a location. Each tower provides a radius and, conceptually, these radii intersect at points, with the true position being where the circles overlap.

For 3D positioning, such as with the Global Positioning System (GPS), you need measurements from at least four satellites. This is because each satellite provides a sphere of possible locations. The intersection of these spheres will give a unique point in three-dimensional space (or more precisely, it will typically give two possible points, one of which can usually be discarded as not being on the Earth's surface). The fourth satellite is also crucial to correct for time discrepancies between the satellite clocks and the receiver's clock.

Do note:
In practice, with real-world imperfections and the desire for increased accuracy, more than the minimum number of measurements might be used.

In conclusion, the term you're looking for, whether in 2D or 3D, is still **trilateration**.